# git: can't remove a file

Tags: git

This happens when I try running the `git cherry-pick <commit sha>` command.

1. `git cherry-pick eaf640bd3ce9f2a4e0650a0c9b9d0fbb920a77a9`
2. error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
       *myfile.java*
   Please move or remove them before you merge.
   Aborting
   fatal: cherry-pick failed

Now I want to remove that file, because I don't need it anymore.

1. `git rm myfile.java`
2. This gets me an error: `fatal: pathspec 'myfile.java' did not match any files`

But I do see the file when running `git status`. If I delete it manually from disk, any time I do `rm -f ./.git/index.lock` it gets recreated.

How do I remove that file permanently not having to care about it?

Comment: Huh? Why are you deleting files in `.git/`? And no, `rm` does not create files.

Comment: Is it the file tracked, untracked or what? When you run `git status`.

Comment: @fedepad It is untracked. I can delete it just by rm, but it still gets recreated when I delete index.lock file.

Comment: Yes, in the case of untracked just rm should do it. But you have some weird stuff going on if it gets recreated...

Comment: Why are you manually deleting `.git/index.lock`? You shouldn't have to do that. That lock file is there for a reason!

Comment: @RolandSmith OK, then tell me what should I do when I get this error: Unable to create ...git/index.lock': File exists. I get this after running cherry-pick

Comment: @wesleyy Normally if a `.git/index.lock` is present, it means that a git command is still running (check with `ps -xa`) or has crashed. You should probably look into that first.

Answer (score 1):

The first error message says the file is untracked, i.e. it is not part of recorded history and git doesn't know about it.

`git rm` gives you an error for the same reason: You can't remove files from the repo that aren't part of it in the first place.

Plain `rm myfile.java` should get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, but then if I do cherry-pick again: 'fatal: Unable to create '.../.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:'
remove the file manually to continue.

Comment: @wesleyy Is there another git process running?

Comment: And then if I remove the .lock file by running: rm -f ./.git/index.lock , myfile.java is recreated again.

Comment: Is there a way to check that? I don't think there is another git process running. I even restarted my machine to make sure no processes are running and tried again. But it was the same.

Comment: @wesleyy What operating system are you on?

Comment: I am on a mac OS.

Comment: @wesleyy Sorry, I don't know Mac OS. But if deleting one file mysteriously makes another file appear, there's probably another process running that keeps re-creating `myfile.java`. What happens if you `mv myfile.java myfile2.java` (i.e. rename it out of the way)?

Comment: If I do that, the file myfile.java still gets created after remocing index.lock file. Then I have both myfile.java and myfile2.java.

Comment: @wesleyy OK, there's something weird going on on your machine. *Something* is running in the background (or maybe as part of your shell prompt?) and messing things up.

Comment: I restarted my machine, and opened *only* the terminal... so what can be running?

Comment: @wesleyy Any services or daemons that run on system startup, anything started by your shell init files (e.g. `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` if you're using bash), any commands contained in `$PROMPT_COMMAND` or `$PS1`, ...

Comment: Perhaps `ps -aux | grep git` might help? Checking what processes have a file in `.git` open might help, but I can't remember that command off the top of my head.

Comment: @wesleyy The command Pockets is not remembering is `fuser` - go to the directory in question and run `fuser .` and it should print a list of process IDs currently using any files in this directory. Then you can use `ps` or Activity Monitor to locate the process using the Process ID (PID).